Adding shape as background?
So i have a uni project to deliver, where i first make my website template and then apply it to html.
I have been trying to reach this result:
Prototype
However, not only does the backgroung layer not work, but i am also not sure of how to insert the triangle shape in the background.
Whenever i try to set the background image, i receive this:
Error
For the background problem i have tried:
header { background-image: url(Livro.png); }
header { background-image: url(Imagens/Livro.png); }
header { background-image: url("Imagens/Livro.png"); }
As long as inserting the entire path to the image and none of them have worked.
As for the triangle shape, i have tried to insert it as an image, but it gets hidden behind the background (that i have set as background-color instead). I've also tried moving it up in the html file but to no avail.
The code i made for this:
sad, i know
part of the page is:
 <body>
        <!-------------- Cabeçalho --------------->

        <header>

            <!-------------- Cabeçalho do Menu --------------->
            <!--??(Sticky)??-->
        
            <div class="menu">
                <h3 class="contactos">Contactos</h3>
                <img class="logo" src="Imagens\Logotipo.png">
                <div class="icone-menu">
                    <div class="retangulo-longo"></div>
                    <div class="retangulo-curto"></div>
                    <div class="retangulo-longo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            
            <!-------------- Rosto da Página --------------->
        <div class="rosto">
            
            <img class="kudu" src="Imagens\Kudu.png">

            <div class="descricao">
                <h1>A LUZ E A ENERGIA</h1>
                <p class="legenda">A luz é um dos fatores ecológicos essenciais e de grande importância em todo o estudo dos ecossistemas, já que constitui a fonte principal de energia para os seres vivos. A luz visível faz parte do espectro que chega ao nosso planeta procedente do Sol. É um fator que regula a existência e os ciclos dos diversos organismos, exercendo ao mesmo tempo uma ação limitadora.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </header>

And the css is:
header {
    background-image: url(Imagens/Livro.png);
}

header h1 {
    grid-column: span 12;
}

header .text-block {
    grid-column: span 12;
}

header .text-block a {
    vertical-align: super;
}


/* ------------------------ Grelha ------------------------ */

.grelha {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}


/* ------------------------ Cabeçalho do Menu ------------------------ */

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    width: 1300px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

.icone-menu {
    position: sticky;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 3px;
    margin-top: 4%;
}

.retangulo-longo {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}
  
.retangulo-curto {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}

.contactos {
    position: sticky;
    margin-top: 4%;
}


/* ------------------------ Rosto da Página ------------------------ */

.rosto {
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
    top: 80px;
}

.kudu {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
}

.descricao {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.legenda {
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}

And this is what im trying to achieve:
Prototype
Im not sure if i made myself clear, and i apologive if i didn't.
Im still kinda new to html so any help would be appreciated!

Studying is all about research. Please don't feel attacked when I approach you to be a student and not any other dev. When you study you need to learn to solve issues yourself and not expect others to do the work for you and and give you the finished project. If you get a degree you need to earn it by your efforts, not by the coding skills of other devs. What have you tried so far? what research have you done? what parts of the documentation you have found do not work for you?

But to give you a little hint to push you in the right direction, there are multiple different approaches to this issue. clip-path, SVG, pseudo-elements, multi-layer images, multiple backgrounds, the help of a graphic designer...

@tacoshy tysm for your feedback! I didn't want to come across as expecting others to give me the finished project, I have indeed tried every method I know so far, and this was my last resort for my upcoming deadline. I was confused as to why the methods I was taught weren't working, so I was looking for a possible alternative.
But I will continue to do my research, as much as earn and build my skills! Ty!


When you are using url() the file should be in the same location as the css.
  folder
    style.css
    image.png


if triangle image is shown, but behind other objects. you can set this to triangle
  z-index: 1;



But what I recommend is using clip-path. this website may also help you.

tysm! today is the last day i have to deliver this and you just saved my life!

Nice to hear that from you:)
